# get the id of task: @task = Worker.where(:name=>params[:worker_id])

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two controllers: workers and tasks.

this is the variable `index of the tasks_controller`:

```
def index
   @task = Worker.where(:name => params[:worker_id])

   respond_to do |format|
        format.html # show.html.erb
        format.json { render json: @worker }
    end
end
```

this is my `index.html.erb of Tasks`:

```
<table>
  <% @task.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= task.name %></td>
      <td><%= task.task %></td>
      <td><%= task.done %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_worker_task_path(task.name,1) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

I have to know what is the id of the task (for example, I set '1').

[image]

I attach my `rake routes` command:

[image]

This is my `edit of the task` (I just wanted to see if I get the relevant task):

```
<table>
    <% @task.each do |task| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= task.name %></td>
        <td><%= task.task %></td>
        <td><%= task.done %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
</table>
```

and this is my `models/worker.rb`:

```
class Worker < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :done, :name, :task
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to the edit page for a particular task, just this will do:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_worker_task_path(task) %>
```

If that is a nested route you probably want to ensure there is a edit_task route so you can do this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %>
```

But as your @task variable is actually a collection of Worker models, if you called the edit_task_path(task) helper then you'll end up on the edit task page, but it'll have passed through the id of a Worker.  Does that make sense?

**Edit**
After a bit of a chat, we created the necessary Task and Worker models, sorted out the migrations and routes.rb file.  Then pointed him towards `new_worker_task_path(worker)` and looked at the worker index page.

Comment: thank you, but I got this error: Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"tasks", :worker_id=>#<Worker id: 1, name: "alon", task: "aa1", done: false, created_at: "2012-12-23 13:40:26", updated_at: "2012-12-23 13:40:26">}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

Comment: Probably because you're using nested routes - do you have an edit_task route?  It'll help if you post your models as well.

Comment: oops, I think I don't have edit_task_path (I run the 'rake routes' command).

Comment: take a look at your routes.rb file and ensure you have an entry for that

Comment: this is my routes.rb:
  resources :workers do
  resources :tasks

Comment: add resources :tasks on a line of it's own, then look at my answer about the @task / Worker issue.

Comment: no, it doesn't work :/ I get an error about edit_task_path. why the rake routes command doesn't show me this path?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21613/discussion-between-edralph-and-alon-shmiel)

Comment: thank you again! I told my twin brother that there is an angel in this world!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should do something like

```
edit_worker_task_path(task, @task)
```

While reading your source code I noticed that you have some weird naming (@task = Worker.where)?

Comment: I got an error. it will be direct me to: http://localhost:3000/workers/alon/tasks/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6205448%3E/edit. in addition, the error is: Couldn't find Worker with name=#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb6205448>

Answer (score 1):

Your link_to should use the helper like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_worker_task_path(id: task.id) %>
```

Also, I recommend you to use I18n to localize your application. Even if you are using only one language, maybe one day you will need a second (or several) other language(s). You can just translate for one language so far.

Your @task variable should be set like following (its weird because you call the variable task but you call the Worker model...):

```
@tasks = Task.where(worker_id: params[:worker_id])
```

Comment: unfortunately, I got error: NameError in TasksController#edit

uninitialized constant TasksController::Task
Rails.root: /home/alon/projects/TODO

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:21:in `edit'
Request

Parameters:

{"worker_id"=>"alon",
 "id"=>"1"}